# Regular expression between a string and symbol Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate a regex for the below string.

I have tried `rule [a-zA-Z0-9 .,/!()-+=_:$@#'&*]+\\ {` but it doesnt work

```
rule apt_regin_2011_32bit_stage1 {
```

I need to parse out apt_regin_2011_32bit_stage1
How can i do this?

I am getting this error in Java:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 36
rule [a-zA-Z0-9 .,/!()-+=_:$@#'&*]+\ {
```

index 36 is the 2nd last character (the space)

Comment: You may need to escape the `/` character.

Comment: You need to escape the `{` at the end and enclose the character class with parentheses, then access Group 1 contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `{` at the end of the pattern (that causes *Illegal repetition* error) and the `-` inside the character class (so  that it could not form a *range* and is treated as a literal hyphen) and enclose the character class with parentheses to define a group, then access Group 1 contents.

```
String s = "rule apt_regin_2011_32bit_stage1 {";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("rule ([a-zA-Z0-9 .,/!()\\-+=_:$@#'&*]+) \\{");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/sK7F3J)

Note that it seems you can match your pattern with a mere

```
"rule\\s+(\\S+)\\s+\\{"
```

See the regex demo, where `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace symbols and `\s+` matches one or more whitespace symbols.

That means you could even split the string with spaces and grab the second element, but it is up to you to choose the right approach.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need